Modeling a bottle with multiple type of geometry
Greetings Blender community,
I'm struggling to model this perfume bottle


this "form" being super complex for me
because it starts from a square and ends up in a ball form and the best result I have come with so far is this :

the way I'm starting is as follow : youtube video
I would like to know if my process from the beginning is wrong and if so could anyone advice me on the way (or which base) to model this and how could I possibly join the multiple type of geometry together ?

Create a UV sphere, cut its bottom, extrude down and fill the bottom, only keep a quarter, create an empty at the same location and create a cube that intersect with the UV sphere:

Give a Boolean modifier to the UV sphere with the cube as Boolean Object and give an Array modifier with the empty as Array Object, rotate the empty 90° on Z:

Apply the Boolean, correct the topology a bit:

When you're good, apply the Array, etc...
